# Copy files using drag-drop from Firefox in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, firefox, copy-paste, drag-and-drop

Usually you can save a picture from the web just by dragging and dropping it from your browser to a folder, right? I have always done that, but in my computer at work that runs on Ubuntu 10.10 I always get an error trying to do it.

I'm using Firefox, and I have this same error since version 3.5, so I think it's not a Firefox problem, but rather an Ubuntu problem. I don't know the exact error message, even because it's not in english, but it's something like "cannot copy to an invalid location".

Does anyone ever experienced this problem? I have the same distro in a laptop but never had any problems.